# How to support window.print() in a embedded web browser?

Tags: qt, printing, webkit

I want to create a `print` button for an HTML file. Well, `window.print()`.
But this does not work because the web browser embedded in the software was developed by my company itself. It does not support print.

This web browser was using WebKit, and I only knew a little about Qt and WebKit.

So, how web browser deals with `window.print`?

Comment: The sequence of the 'window.print' for QT port is:
window.print-> DOMWindow::print -> Chrome::print -> ChromeClient::print (ChromClientQt.cpp) -> emit m_webPage->printRequested
By default, the the QWebPage::printRequested is not connected to any slot.
You should add a slot like 'LauncherWindow::print' do (Show a preview dialog and print using QWebFrame::print).

If your customized web browser doesn't use QT port, you need to implement the 'print' feature for your port.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Shen: I think your comment deserves to be promoted to a full answer. As it is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sending the content of the HTML/CSS (or a link) via AJAX to a server side print server, which then renders the HTML and sends it to the network printer. Another option is to create a browser plugin with NSAPI (C++). Another option is to embed a Java applet, which takes the HTML, renders it, and sends it to the printer.

Comment: As I said to @twodave, there is a setup to make window.print works in QT. It will be the answer to the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the HTML file so that if a query string argument like ?print=1 is present it will automatically call window.print(). Then just open your-file.html?print=1 in a separate browser process.

Comment: In objective-c webkit, you need to set a delegate to make window.print() works. Qt, supposedly, need something like this to make window.print() works too. What is needed is the anwser to this question.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I must have misread. Going to upvote the guy who had the answer then.